# Filter no array voltando nulo

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, estou com essa const

```
export const STATUS = [{
  0: 'Rascunho',
  1: 'Enviado',
  2: 'Processando',
  9: 'Processado',
  3: 'Agendado',
  4: 'Protocolizado',
  5: 'Suspenso',
  6: 'Erro protocolo',
  7: 'Erro processamento',
  8: 'Erro leitura',
}];
```

e estou tentando acessar os valores usando o seguinte método

```
  public constantFormatter(params) {
    const status = STATUS.filter((p) => p === params.value);
  }
```

porém esta sempre retornando vazio e não estou conseguindo entender o porque, será que alguém já teve o mesmo problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto é porque `STATUS` é um array de objetos com dentro os seus status, e você está iterando neste array e não nos valores do objeto do mesmo, se você sabe que os seus valores existem dentro ao primeiro objeto deste array você poder usar o [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) que irá retornar um array a partir dos valores do objeto passado. Exemplo:

```js
const STATUS = [{
  0: 'Rascunho',
  1: 'Enviado',
  2: 'Processando',
  9: 'Processado',
  3: 'Agendado',
  4: 'Protocolizado',
  5: 'Suspenso',
  6: 'Erro protocolo',
  7: 'Erro processamento',
  8: 'Erro leitura',
}];

function findValue(value){
  // Values agora é um array de Strings que contém todos os valores do objeto que está na posição 0 do array STATUS
  const values = Object.values(STATUS[0]);
  
  return values.find(v => v === value);
}

console.log(findValue('Enviado')); // Enviado
```

Antes de prosseguir fazendo perguntas a outras pessoas sobre como resolver certos problemas te aconselho a antes fazer um debug do seu código, faça um `console.log` das suas variáveis, veja qual é o valor delas em determinado momento, faça uso do debbuger, este tipo de problema você pode resolver simplesmente olhando o valor das variáveis.